# Create columns in dataframe by applying filters to other columns

Tags: python, pandas

Following is my dataset:

| class | StudentName | Age | Height | Weight | PassedExam |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Joe | 10 | 150 | 56 | Pass |
| 5 | Nick | 10 | 153 | 54 | Fail |
| 5 | Adam | 10 | 156 | 61 | Pass |
| 4 | Julia | 9 | 148 | 50 | Pass |
| 7 | George | 12 | 156 | 59 | Fail |
| 5 | Robert | 10 | 157 | 60 | Pass |
| 6 | Sam | 11 | 155 | 60 | Pass |
| 6 | travis | 11 | 153 | 63 | Pass |

I want select Students if any of the below conditions apply:

Height greater than 150

Passed Exam is equal to 'Pass'

And further create two columns valid and Invalid in output as follows:

| class | ValidStudent | InvalidStudent | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Adam,Robert | Joe,Nick | 51,60,56,54 |
| 6 | Sam,travis |  | 60,63 |
| 4 |  | Julia | 50 |
| 7 |  | George | 59 |

Following is my code to select rows with filter values but I am not able to create the columns:

```
df.loc[(df['PassedExam'] == 'Pass') & (df['Height'] > 150)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df_valid = df[(df['PassedExam'] == 'Pass') & (df['Height'] > 150)]
df_valid = df_valid.groupby('class').agg(ValidStudent = pd.NamedAgg(column="StudentName", aggfunc=",".join)).reset_index()

df_invalid = df[(df['PassedExam'] != 'Pass') | (df['Height'] <= 150)]
df_invalid = df_invalid.groupby('class').agg(InvalidStudent = pd.NamedAgg(column="StudentName", aggfunc=",".join)).reset_index()

df_valid = df_valid.merge(df_invalid, how='outer', on='class')
df_valid = df_valid.merge(df.groupby('class').agg(Weight = pd.NamedAgg(column="Weight", aggfunc=",".join)),
                          how='left', on=['class'])
```

`OUTPUT`

```
   class ValidStudent InvalidStudent       Weight
0      5  Adam,Robert       Joe,Nick  56,54,61,60
1      6   Sam,travis            NaN        60,63
2      4          NaN          Julia           50
3      7          NaN         George           59
```